# PDO Connect truncated username

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been given the task of learning and updating many php scripts from using mysqli to PDO.
For some unknown reason, when I attempt to connect to our mysql database, it's truncating the username.
This is my php:

```
try{
    $user = "this_is_a_really_really_really_long_user_name";
    echo $user."\n";
    $pass = "StackOverflowExample";
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example", $user, $pass);
}
catch(PDOException $err){echo $err->getMessage(); $error = true;}
```

The echo returns:

```
this_is_a_really_really_really_long_user_name
```

Then my catch statement outputs:

```
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'this_is_a_really'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

As you can see, the username is being truncated.
Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure MySQL actually supports such long usernames - does it work in the command line client?

Comment: If it does work, I suggest filing a bug on bugs.php.net :)

Comment: It does work because i'm using the same username in a mysqli_connect statement: $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","example","StackOverflowExample","this_is_a_really_really_really_long_user_name");

Comment: Weird. File a bug on http://bugs.php.net/ maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL user names can be up to **16 characters long**. Operating system user names, because they are completely unrelated to MySQL user names, may be of a different maximum length. For example, Unix user names typically are limited to **eight characters**.

Comment: Can you provide sources for "unix" user names limit? Just added an `abcdefghijklmnop` in a FreeBSD.